Может ли местоимение замещать слово через одно предложение?
«Кроме того, важно прививать нравственные ценности. Лучше всего это делать, пока ребёнок маленький. Несмотря на распространённое мнение, что в таком возрасте он не способен понять и оценить их важность, не стоит списывать данный совет со счетов». Корректна ли такая замена при разрыве в одно предложение? Существуют ли какие-то правила?


Могу предположить, что это нежелательно. Такое расположение личного местоимения их будет неоправданным и может считаться стилистической ошибкой. Возможное редактирование:

Кроме того, важно прививать нравственные ценности, и лучше всего это делать, пока ребёнок маленький. Несмотря на распространённое мнение, что в таком возрасте он не способен понять и оценить их важность, не стоит списывать данный совет со счетов.

О правилах

Употребление личных местоимений регулирует правило Розенталя §169. Личные местоимения.
  Местоимение 3-го лица (он, она, оно, они) обычно заменяет 
  ближайшее к нему предшествующее существительное в форме 
  того же рода и числа. Однако эта связь местоимения с 
  существительным определяется иногда смыслом, а не 
  формально порядком слов, например: Туристы побывали во 
  многих городах страны: они интересовались прежде всего 
  местными историческими достопримечательностями (не 
  вызывает сомнений, что местоимение они относится к более 
  отдаленному существительному туристы, а не к ближе 
  стоящему городах).

  Возможность соотнесения местоимения с разными словами в 
  предшествующем тексте может служить источником неясности 
  или двусмысленности.

Мы видим, что позиция местоимения очень важна даже в пределах одного предложения.
В книге В. В. Бабайцевой "Русский язык 10 – 11 класс (углубленное изучение)" местоимения рассмотрены как средства связи предложений: § 19. Местоименные слова.
Там говорится, что местоимения вводятся в следующее предложение за предшествующим.
https://vk.com/doc1290373_660267746?hash=VjTVzSOy2Yfi2OT7Ye9LCrSW0XJrvdQpt7kRRVciZv0
